# java file in Eclipse got messed up with weird characters

Tags: java, android, eclipse, encoding, binary

My java file got messed up. It has some binary encoding according to this site: http://lajm.eu/emil/encoding/. It says it has: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

So how is my java file suddenly encoded in binary? And more important, how can I recover my code?

[image]

Comment: There could be so many things like your file system may have got corrupted etc. It really cant be determined by this this particular case in isolation. Check your disk for any filesystem corruption.

Comment: I have checked my disk, there are not corruptions. It would be weird to have just 1 java file corrupted and all the others are still normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check your file encoding by going to `edit`->`set encoding`. see what does it say. Before you panic also be sure to restart Eclipse. It sometimes happens that strange characters are shown, but usually a restart fixes it.

**EDIT** As for how can you restore a version of your file: `Every time you modify a file in Eclipse, a copy of the old contents is kept in the local history.` (see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_is_the_workspace_local_history_stored?)). You can find your file in: `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history` of your workspace. Hopefully this will help you.

**EDIT 2** Ah actually the file there is ugly looking binary, but at least is stored. You can try from Eclipse: select your file -> right click -> replace with -> local history.

Comment: I already restarted Eclipse and I tried to fix it with setting the workspace encoding in preferences to UTF-8. So at Edit > Set Encoding it says : Default (inhereted from container: UTF-8)

Comment: Is there a chance you replaced the java code with binary data while executing some of your methods?

Comment: How would I have done that? Yesterday I was just coding and I build a valid working apk file which runs on my phone. Today I start Eclipse again and I notice the messed up file. Did nothing weird and nothing I haven't done before for many many times.

Comment: I added how you can restore an older version of the file from Eclipse in my answer.

Comment: @Boris Strandjev: I can't thank you enough. Insanity was on my doorstep after I thought I'd lost 3K lines of code. Discovering this nugget generated the most excitement I've ever had on StackOverflow!